# Which test should I report, ANOVA or Mann-Whitney?

Tags: anova, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

My data set is small, with roughly 12 in each group (two groups).  In addition, the distribution of the data is not normal. As a result, I ran a Mann-Whitney U test.

However, I also ran a one-way ANOVA and got the exact same results.  Which test should I report and it is okay to say that I ran both with equal results but chose to report only the ANOVA?

Answer (score 3):

Report the result from the Mann Whitney test that is the appropriate test irrespective of whether or not the F test gives you the same result.